# Using Template Schema in XML view

Tags: xml, sapui5

I am trying to test the [new XML template preprocessing features](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/c27d49caa48e424eb75391ae85da2134.html) of OpenUI5 `1.30.x`.

However, the namespacing seems to be messed up.

My view,

```xml
<mvc:View
  controllerName="local.controller"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:template="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.template/1">
  <List
    items="{/Categories}">
    <StandardListItem title="{Name}" info="{ID}" />
  </List>
  <Label text="Categories with ID > 0:" />
  <template:repeat list="{/Categories}" var="cat">
    <template:if test="{= ${cat>ID} > 0 }">
      <Label text="{cat>Name}" />
      <Text text="{cat>ID}" />      
    </template:if>
  </template:repeat>
</mvc:View>
```

The error I see in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: failed to load 'http://schemas/sap/com/sapui5/extension/sap/ui/core/template/1/repeat.js' 
from https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.30.7/resources/http://schemas/sap/com/sapui5/extension/sap/ui/core/template/1/repeat.js
: 404 - Not Found
```

And my UI5 bootstrap script looks like:

```
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
        src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.30.7/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
        data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
        data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
        data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex">
</script>
```

All of the above examples can be seen in this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/koluku/edit?html,output

I'm assuming there's a library registration I need to do that I'm not doing? Otherwise UI5 wouldn't try to load the template schema under the library's path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the "[XML Templating in OpenUI5](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/5ee619fc1370463ea674ee04b65ed83b.html)" documentation, it appears that you must pass the preprocessor info into the view upon view instantiation:

```
var oTemplateView = sap.ui.view({
    preprocessors: {
      xml: {
        bindingContexts: {
          meta: oMetaModel.getMetaContext(sPath)
        },
        models: {
          meta: oMetaModel
        }
      }
    },
    type: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML,
    viewName: "sap.ui.core.sample.ViewTemplate.tiny.Template"
  });
```

Comment: I did miss that one-liner in the documentation. I saw the `<mvc:View />` declaration and assumed this would also work with the router (which I would use in a real-world situation). [GitHub issue #428](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/428) mentions a similar situation or future enhancement request. We'll have to track this as an enhancement going forward. I misunderstood the feature, sadly.